# Restore AWS RDS backup from one DB ro another DB by using some restoration method

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

My requirement is to create rds DB ( which is already existing in AWS ) using cloudformation in AWS. I need to take backup of existing DB and restore it to newly created RDS from stack.
Could you please give me solution on this

Answer (score 0):

you can use either automated snapshots or manual ones to recreate DB with CloudFormation, you just need to pass the snapshot ID to `DBSnapshotIdentifier`.

so e.g

```
  MasterDB:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBName: !Ref 'DBName'
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref 'DBAllocatedStorage'
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref 'DBInstanceClass'
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: !Ref 'DBUser'
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref 'DBPassword'
      MultiAZ: !Ref 'MultiAZ'
      DBSnapshotIdentifier: !Ref YOUR_SNAPSHOT_ID
```

you can find more info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbinstance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-dbsnapshotidentifier)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually I cant go with solution. I need some solution without adding any snapshot information to cftemplate  @zelaskov

Comment: do you mean that you cannot pass ID in the template itself? if so, you can pass it as a parameter, even pull it from CI/CD environment e.g

Comment: Yeah thats a good idea to provide params in CICD.  If you have any other alternate solution could you please share?

Comment: you can pass parameters to `updateStack` command in CloudFormation, so something like `aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name $YOUR_STACK_NAME --template-url $YOUR_TEMPLATE_URL --parameters ParameterKey=$YOUR_KEY_NAME,ParameterValue=$YOUR_VALUE` this way you can pull out those values from CI/CD